# SQL queries to create variable products on woocommerce

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create variable products using mysql and php. 
I have found that woocommerce stores products on wp_posts table but with type 'product'

Also variations are saved on the same table but with 'post_parent' = produt id

Also on wp_term_relationships i set the term_taxonomy_id = 6 for variable products.

On wp_postmeta i have added some data for variation.

Product is created but with no variations.
Can any one help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Each variation is stored as its own product in the wp_posts table and refers to the original product in the post_parent field.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank for commenting but i have specified it on my question. Also after i create variations as other products they will not show up

Answer (score 0):

If you are already creating the variable product and want to add variations to that product the code given below will help you.

1- suppose you have one attribute that is size with variations like -

```
$avail_attributes = array(
'2xl',
'xl',
'lg',
);
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $avail_attributes, 'pa_size');
$thedata = Array('pa_size'=>Array(
'name'=>'pa_size',
'value'=>'',
'is_visible' => '1',
'is_variation' => '1',
'is_taxonomy' => '1'
));
update_post_meta( $new_post_id,'_product_attributes',$thedata);
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_weight', "0.06" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', "skutest1");
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock', "100" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
```

2- Now what you have to do is just add the variations to the product like this--

```
$i=1;
while ($i<=5) {
$post = array(
'post_title'=> 'Variation #' . $i . ' of 5 for prdct#'. $post_id,
'post_name' => 'product-' . $post_id . '-variation-' . $i,
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_parent' => $post_id,
'post_type' => 'product_variation',
'guid'=>home_url() . '/?product_variation=product-' . $post_id . '-variation-' . $i
);
$attID = wp_insert_post( $post );
$logtxt .= "Attribute inserted with ID: $attID\n";
$variation_id = $post_id + 1;
$variation_two = $variation_id + 1;
$variation_three = $variation_two + 1;
$variation_four = $variation_three + 1;
$variation_five = $variation_four + 1;
update_post_meta($variation_id, 'attribute_pa_size', '2xl'); update_post_meta($variation_id, '_price', 21.99);
update_post_meta($variation_id, '_regular_price', '21.99');
wp_set_object_terms($variation_id, $avail_attributes, 'pa_size');
$thedata = Array('pa_size'=>Array(
'name'=>'2xl',
'value'=>'',
'is_visible' => '1',
'is_variation' => '1',
'is_taxonomy' => '1'
));
update_post_meta( $variation_id,'_product_attributes',$thedata);
update_post_meta( $variation_two, 'attribute_pa_size', 'xl');
update_post_meta( $variation_two, '_price', 20.99 );
update_post_meta( $variation_two, '_regular_price', '20.99');
wp_set_object_terms($variation_two, $avail_attributes, 'pa_size');
$thedata = Array('pa_size'=>Array(
'name'=>'xl',
'value'=>'',
'is_visible' => '1',
'is_variation' => '1',
'is_taxonomy' => '1'
));
update_post_meta( $variation_two,'_product_attributes',$thedata);
update_post_meta( $variation_three, 'attribute_pa_size', 'lg');
update_post_meta( $variation_three, '_price', 18.99 );
update_post_meta( $variation_three, '_regular_price', '18.99');
wp_set_object_terms($variation_three, $avail_attributes, 'pa_size');
$thedata = Array('pa_size'=>Array(
'name'=>'lg',
'value'=>'',
'is_visible' => '1',
'is_variation' => '1',
'is_taxonomy' => '1'
));
update_post_meta( $variation_three,'_product_attributes',$thedata);
update_post_meta( $variation_four, 'attribute_pa_size', 'md');
update_post_meta( $variation_four, '_price', 18.99 );
update_post_meta( $variation_four, '_regular_price', '18.99');
$i++;
}
```